# Edit image 'src' vs replace 'img' tag in a Div?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
    var rightnow=0; var highone=8;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#next-img").click(function(){
    rightnow=rightnow+1; if (rightnow>highone) {rightnow=1;}; 
    $(".img-class").attr('src',"http://example.com/images/abc_"+rightnow+".jpg");
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
  });
});

function doneLoading() {
    var loadtime1 = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
    $("#stats span").html(loadtime1);

<img class="img-class" height="300" src="" onload="doneLoading()"/>
```

I am using this code to display an image on screen. Each time 'next' button is clicked, it changes the 'src' of img tag to display the next image. So the div containing the image never goes empty.
The doneLoading() function helps me calculate the time of image load. The previous image stays on screen till the next image loads(the window does not go blank). 
Now I am looking to add these features:

1) When 'next' is clicked, fade or remove the present image while the next image loads.

2) Display a loading indicator while the next image loads.

3) Continue to display the image load time.

My question:

Should I try to build on my present method or should I use something like:

```
    $("#next-img").click(function() {
      $("#imageBox").html("<img src=' + this.href + '>");
});
```

or this...

```
    $("#next-img").click(function() {
      $("#imageBox").html($("<img>").attr("src", this.href));
});
```

If someone can highlight the advantage of one method over the other, it would be great. To me it seems .load and .html methods may be what I should do but I am looking for expert opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is probably negligible, but personally I would only update the `src` *property*:

```
$(".img-class").prop('src', 'http://example.org/...');
```

The alternative is create the tag like this:

```
var $img = $('<img>', {
    src: this.href
});
$("#imageBox").html($img);
```

Comment: so which ever way I choose, I should be able to incorporate features 1,2 and 3 mentioned in my question?

Comment: @TanveerDewan Yeah, I don't see why not.

Comment: do you have a sample code to fade/remove the present image while the next one loads?

Comment: @TanveerDewan Isn't there a fade animation in jQuery? Loading an image in the background is done with `var i = new Image(); i.onload = function() { ... }; i.src = '...'`.